# Shooting eight-ball legally and sank the opponent's ball instead, what happens?

Tags: rules, pool

If I am shooting the eight-ball for the game, hit the eight-ball, but sink the opponent's ball and the eight-ball does not go down, what happens?

Answer (score 3):

It is your opponent's turn.

You were on the 8 and designated the pocket. With the cue ball, you struck *your* ball first, the 8 ball, which is the 1st requirement for a legal hit.  A ball - as in *any ball* - was pocketed, or hit a rail, which meets the 2nd and final requirement for a legal hit.  There was no foul, nor did you pocket your ball.  Therefore, your turn is over.